# Dynamodb - GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using python to query a dynamodb table,however I'm using two keys in the getitem call that are not part of the primary key or sort key.I created a global index that contains these two keys, but I still get the same error.

```
  response = table.get_item(
            Key={
                'player_id': 22892251,'type': 1
            }
        )
  item = response['Item']
  print(item)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `GetItem` to fetch data from a global secondary index. This is not supported. The `GetItem` API returns exactly 1 item, which is only possible because the Primary Key (Partition + Sort Key) is guaranteed to be unique in the base table.

This is not the case for global secondary indexes, which is why `GetItem` is not supported here. It requires a guarantee that the underlying data structure does not give.

The way to fetch this data is to use the `Query` operation that *can* return multiple items:

```py
import boto3

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("table_name")

response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key("player_id").eq(number) & Key("type").eq(number),
    IndexName="player_id-type-index"
)

items = response["Items"]

if len(items) > 1:
    raise RuntimeError("Something broke our unique expectation")

print(items[0])
```

It's on your app to ensure that the entries are unique if you require it. Here's an example that lets you detect if this assumption got broken somehow.

Comment: @Lee Hannigan - the sentence is as intended ;-) `GetItem` can retrieve exactly one item, because the primary key on the base table needs to be unique.

Comment: It read wrong in my head, but now that I've read it again you were in fact correct. I was reading it as it relates to an index but you stated base table. Apologies.

Comment: No worries - my first draft was more convoluted than necessary. I tried to phrase it more clearly now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot issue a `GetItem` against a secondary index as items are not unique.

You must use a [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) request.

```
response = table.query(
IndexName='player_id-type-index'
KeyConditionExpression=Key('player_id').eq(22892251) & Key('type').eq(1) )
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```